# What does the "Phi" sign stand for in musical notation?

Tags: theory, chords

I have encountered this symbol:

[image]

F sharp "phi"

Any idea what should be played here?

Comment: In term of what notes are contained in a half-diminished chord, see the answers below (here this is F#, A, C, E, and you may be able to play the flat G depending on style and taste). Functionally, this is pretty much always the II in a minor II-V-I, here F#ø / B7 (alt, etc) / Emin (maj7, or 6/9, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a half diminished chord. Otherwise known as m7b5. So F#<sup>ø</sup> will be F#, A, C, E, as F# = root, A = m3, C = b5 and E = m7. It's close to 'phi' but isn't exactly. Can't remember what it's actually called - and worse, can't find it on a qwerty board.

Comment: Probably stolen from the Dutch or Swedish char set :-)

Comment: It's just a degree symbol (or other raised circle) with a diagonal slash though it. I think it's only used as the half diminished symbol. I've never heard it called anything else.

Comment: Note that, in Tim's answer, the symbol he uses is actually the *fully*-diminished symbol. The chord he spells *is* the half-diminished seventh you're asking about, but the character is a little off!

Comment: @Richard - I did me best! The zero looks good, with a line through, on screen,  until it appears on this page. Must find a Dutch or Swedish keyboard...

Comment: I feel your pain :-) I just wanted to clarify, that's all.

Comment: @xnakos - o.k., now share the secret with us! Would it be a Greek letter?

Comment: Actually, neither Dutch nor Swedish contain the letter 'ø'. It is used in modern Danish and Norwegian. The Swedish equivalent is 'ö'.

Comment: @Tim Shhh... I do not have it on my keyboard... I indulged in a bit of copy-and-pasting... Living the best of the UTF-8 era... :)

Comment: So, so far, musicians use a symbol with no name? Possibly 'The symbol formerly known as...?'

Comment: @Tim How does "F-sharp Saturn" sound? It cannot be unseen, can it? :)

Comment: @xnakos - we may be onto something here. Might have to check with Gustav, though.

Comment: Probably the notation comes from the notation ° for the diminished chord. Half diminished is ° with a stroke.

Answer (score 4):

That is the sign for a half diminished chord.

> Half-diminished seventh chords are often symbolized as a circle with a
>   diagonal line through it, as in Cø. It also can be represented as
>   m7♭5, -7♭5, m7(♭5) etc.
>
> The terms and symbols for this chord break expectations that derive
>   from the usual system of chord nomenclature. Normally a symbol like
>   "Bdim" indicates a diminished triad and "B7" indicates a major triad
>   plus a minor seventh. Thus one would expect the term "Bdim7" to
>   indicate a diminished triad plus a minor seventh. Instead, it means a
>   diminished triad plus a diminished seventh. To make this distinction
>   clear, the term "half-diminished" and the ø symbol (ø) were invented.
>   Since the term dim7 (as in Bdim7) meant something else, the accurate
>   but unwieldy term "minor seventh flat five" (as in Bø7))(About this
>   sound Play (help·info)) came to be used.[5]

[SOURCE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-diminished_seventh_chord)